# convert object[] args from formula to Value before invoke in C#

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

I am passing `object[]` args to export DataTable to Excel,

```
range.GetType().InvokeMember("Value", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, range2, args);
```

Here args are as excel formulas for each value. If I export it, it displays the formulas as it is.

How to display the values of those formulas?

Comment: unclear,please explain more

Comment: I am passing the data in excel formula format from DB for exporting  to excel.for ex., args has the first data as
=CONCATENATE("Test","Data") . like wise i m  passing all the values through the formula. but after exporting it to excel , that particular column shows the formula as it is but not the formula result. it shows like 
=CONCATENATE("Test","Data"). but i want it as "Test Data" in excel sheet column.